# Вставка заданной строки в текст

Tags: php

Необходимо вставить заданную строку (будь то *html*-код или обычная строка) в уже готовый текст.
Как это реализовать на *php*?

То есть, в случайном месте текста необходимо вставить заданную строку.

Пример текста «до»:

> Aenean ex justo, faucibus quis suscipit ac, pharetra sit amet ligula. Sed sed mi ligula. Cras pellentesque bibendum augue nec varius. Fusce velit dolor,  rhoncus id nisl eu, ultricies auctor quam. Integer dictum pellentesque fringilla. Donec a ligula id velit vehicula sollicitudin. Nam non lorem vel mi bibendum tristique at in erat. Ut maximus, ante id mollis aliquet, tortor mauris volutpat arcu, sed scelerisque arcu purus euismod eros

и «после»:

> Aenean ex justo, faucibus quis suscipit ac, pharetra sit amet ligula. Sed sed mi ligula. Cras pellentesque **Строкааааа** bibendum augue nec varius. Fusce velit dolor, вставленная строка rhoncus id nisl eu, ultricies auctor quam. Integer dictum pellentesque fringilla. Donec a ligula id velit vehicula sollicitudin. Nam non lorem vel mi bibendum tristique at in erat. Ut maximus, ante id mollis aliquet, tortor mauris volutpat arcu, sed scelerisque arcu purus euismod eros

Comment: Можно поподробнее, что именно куда вставить, и код хоть какой-нибудь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно достичь JavaScript'ом.

jQuery:

```
 elementHTML = $("selector").html();
 $("selector").html(elementHTML.substring(0,20) + stroka + elementHTML.substring(20,elementHTML.lenth-1));
```

JavaScript:

```
elementHTML = document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML;
document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = elementHTML.substring(0,20) + stroka + elementHTML.substring(20,elementHTML.lenth-1)
```

Если принципиально нужен PHP то просто загоните все это в echo:

```
echo "<script>JS код</script>";
```

Comment: Понимаете, мне нужно чтобы реализация была с помощью _php_. Потому что сначала текст будет обрабатывать скрипт, класть в базу его уже с вставленными словами и потом выводить на страницу. А выставленные строки должны быть видны поисковым системам (а проблема в том что javascript они не обрабатывают).

Comment: в php есть аналогичная функция substr(), посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Она же вроде возвращает подстроку?

Comment: ну так разломайте ее так же как я сделал в примере. Сначала до нужного место, потом вставить ваш текст, потом вставить остальное

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Юрию, вот что получилось (может кому - то пригодится) :

```
<?php
$text = 'Наш любимый текс ура ура ура ура';
$string = " Строка ";
$text1 = substr ($text, 0,20);
$text2 = substr ($text, 20);
echo $text1 .    $string   .  $text2;
?>
```